# Validating http response codes with Selenium automation

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

Need to validate the http status codes of the pages of the website. Is there an option with Selenium webdriver to check?

Answer (score 1):

Found out solution for my question. It is not with selenium webdriver. 
With webinject(http://webinject.org) tool.

Sample snippet from testcase.xml:

```
<testcases repeat="1">

 <case
   id="1"
   description1="test 404 page"
   description2="Follow redirect"
   method="post"
   url="http://localhost/test"
   verifyresponsecode="200"
   parseresponse="Location:|\n"
   errormessage="Custom File not found"
/>
</testcases>
```